scipy.ndimage has a map_coordinates function that pulls in values from a source to a target. Is there a function that pushes from source to target?
scipy.ndimage has a function map_coordinates described here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html
it allows for a source volume and a mapping to be provided. This mapping is in the target space and states for every voxel in the target space the location in the source space of that value. In this sense it is pulling in from the source space. What about the opposite, is there a function that allows for a source volume to be provided and a mapping of vectors which say how far each value should be moved to create the source space? This is useful for creating intermediary stages through division.
To borrow from the scipy example what map_coordinates provides is

from scipy import ndimage

import numpy as np

a = np.arange(4.).reshape((2, 2))
print(a)
>> array([[  0.,   1.],
          [  2.,   3.]])

print(ndimage.map_coordinates(a, [[0.5, 1], [0.5, 1]], order=1))
>> array([ 1.5,  3])

whereas what I would want is

from scipy import ndimage

import numpy as np

a = np.arange(4.).reshape((2, 2))
print(a)
>> array([[  0.,   1.],
          [  2.,   3.]])

deformation = np.array([[[0.5,0.5],[1,1]],
                         [[0,0.5],[1,0.5]])

apply_deformation_with_interpolation(a,deformation)


